# Input form in div of jquery hover causing div to close when input box is moused over

Tags: jquery, html

completely ignorant to jquery so please excuse me if incorrect terms used here.
as seen on jsfiddle failed attempt, i have a login form embedded into a hover state animation using jquery. However if i mouse to select any items in the drop menu the hover state is released and the div is closed. What am i doing wrong here? In addition to the hover issue with the input, how what do i need to add to the script in order for the tab text to remain in the hover state color and background as you mouse over the div?

http://jsfiddle.net/K55ct/171

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#footerSlideContainer').hover(function () {
        $('#footerSlideContent').animate({
            height: '250px'
        });
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
    },

    function () {
        $('#footerSlideContent').animate({
            height: '0px'
        });
        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
    });
});
```

Comment: Looks fine in Safari :-)

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome too :)

Comment: The problem occurs in Firefox. I might suggest that hover-based animations of that magnitude don't usually make for a good user experience.

Comment: I don't see an opening form tag.

Comment: In Chrome, if you select an entry from the drop-down below the yellow box, it closes. Also, if you hover away from the drop-down the box also closes.

Comment: Fiddle updated to fix a couple HTML issues.

Comment: Still not able to get this done.....has to be a easy way for a simple login form to rest inside jquery without closing the tab ? No ?